# No me carga las vistas diseño en Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, matisse

Por algun motivo, cuando quiero ver cualquier `JFrame` en la vista de diceño, netbeans no me muestra nada. Se queda eternamente con la leyenda "Loading ..." en el centro del `JFrame` y no carga ni un solo componente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tal vez el archivo `.form` fue creado en otra aplicacion o esta corrupto, no te sabriamos decir sin verlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lineas generales estás usando una orden o instrucción "obsoleta" que ya ha sido dada de baja en las nuevas versiones del JDK de Java. Revísalo, actualiza, por ahi encontrarás la solución.

Comment: Hola Juan. Evidentemente debe ser algo de lo que decis. Se soluciono actualizando el NetBeans por una versión mas nueva. Gracias!!!